# HTML is not touching top of the browser

Tags: html, css

My website is not touching top of the browser. There is little gap at the top.

Openly speaking, body is not touching top of the window and I want it to touch the top.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            Example
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
}

#header
{
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}

#header h1 { margin: 0; }

#navigation
{
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    background: #333;
}

#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover 
{ 
    background: #383; 
}
```

And here is example:

http://jsfiddle.net/deerox/YxwqX/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick fix**, stylize the body and html tags like so:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Further read, CSS Reset:**

A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.

In case you didn’t know, **every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet**, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain amount of padding to almost everything. Ever wondered why Submit buttons look different in every browser?

Obviously this creates a certain amount of headaches for CSS authors, who can’t work out how to make their websites look the same in every browser. (NB: article coming soon about why this is a false notion!)

Using a CSS Reset, CSS authors can force every browser to have all its styles reset to null, thus avoiding cross-browser differences as much as possible.

*([source](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/))*

**Resources:**

I'm using [HTML5 reset](https://raw.github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset/master/_/css/style.css), it's my favorite.

Additional commonly used reset techniques can be found all together at the front page of  http://cssreset.com/

Comment: Just beware of some common resets to the bullet styles or the strong tag, they often get their styles removed and then your lists don't have bullets and the text between the strong tag is not bold. You have to set them your own to how you want them to be.

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers treat the HTML elements the same way.

You should use a reset css file to undo styling by browsers. (simply [google](http://www.google.com) for [css reset](http://www.google.com?q=css%20reset))

In this case it is the `<body>` tag which has a standard margin/padding in your browser.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
html,body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Seems you are new to CSS. You may have to use CSS browser reset for a cross-browser compatible design.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is from so long ago, but I ran into this problem so many times and always came to this post, so now that I've found the fix, I hope this helps somebody.

Code here:

```css
// fixes width
body {
    margin: 0;
}

// fixes height
#header {
    display: flex;
}
```